# Genetic algorithm: problem of convergence

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to find the solution of the one-max problem with a genetic algorithm, but it is not converging, instead the maximum fitness is getting lower. I can't see why it's not working; I tried to execute the functions on their own and they worked, I'm not sure about the calling in the main though.the one max problem is when you have a population N of binary individuals (1/0) of length m, and you want to optimize your population so you generate at least one individual containing only 1s (in my case 0s)

Here's my code:

```py
import random

def fitness(individual):
    i = 0
    for m in individual:
        if m == 0:
            i += 1
    return i

def selection(pop):
    chosen = []
    for i in range(len(pop)):
        aspirants = []
        macs = []
        for j in range(3):
            aspirants.append(random.choice(pop))
        if fitness(aspirants[0]) > fitness(aspirants[1]):
            if fitness(aspirants[0]) > fitness(aspirants[2]):
                macs = aspirants[0]
            else: macs = aspirants[2]
        else:
            if fitness(aspirants[1]) > fitness(aspirants[2]):
                macs = aspirants[1]
            else: macs = aspirants[2]
        chosen.append(macs)
    return chosen

def crossover(offspring):
    for child1, child2 in zip(offspring[::2], offspring[1::2]):
        if random.random() < 0.7:
            child1[50:100], child2[50:100]=child2[50:100], child1[50:100]

def mutate(offspring):
    for mut in offspring:
        if random.random() < 0.3:
            for i in range(len(mut)):
                if random.random() < 0.05:
                    mut[i] = type(mut[i])(not mut[i])

def gen_individ():
    ind = []
    for s in range(100):
        ind.append(random.randint(0, 1))
    return ind

def gen_pop():
    pop = []  
    for s in range(300):
        pop.append(gen_individ())
    return pop

g = 0
popul = gen_pop()
print("length of pop = %i "% len(popul))
fits = []
for k in popul:
    fits.append(fitness(k))    
print("best fitness before = %i"% max(fits))
while(max(fits) < 100 and g < 100):   
    g += 1
    offspring = []
    offspring = selection(popul)
    crossover(offspring)
    mutate(offspring)
    popul.clear()
    popul[:] = offspring
    fits.clear()
    for k in popul:
    fits.append(fitness(k))
print("lenght of pop = %i "% len(popul))
print("best fitness after = %i"% max(fits))  
print("generation : %i"%g)
```

Comment: What is the "one-max problem"?

Comment: the one max problem is when you have a population N of binary individuals (1/0) of length m, and you want to optimize your population so you generate at least one individual containing only 1s (in my case 0s)

Comment: Please edit your question post with this information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that in all your functions, you always just modify the same individuals instead of creating copies. For instance, in the `selection` function you repeatedly select the best-out-of-three (in a rather convoluted way), and then insert multiple *references* to that same list into the `chosen` list. Later, when you `mutate` any of those, you mutate all the references. In the end you might even end up with just `N` references to the same list, at which point obviously no more actual selection can take place.

Instead, you should create copies of the lists. This can happen in different places: in your main method, in `mutate` and `recombine`, or in the `selection` for the next iteration. I'll put it into `selection`, mainly for the reason that this function can be improved in other ways, too:

```
def selection(pop):
    chosen = []
    for i in range(len(pop)):
        # a lot shorter
        aspirants = random.sample(pop, 3)
        macs = max(aspirants, key=fitness)
        # create COPIES of the individual, not multiple references
        chosen.append(macs[:])
    return chosen
```

With this, you should get a quality of 100 each time.

Comment: indeed, as it appears this is the problem, i am new to python, i don't see this quit clearly though.